# Striving Hard to find a way to use array with COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using below formula to count the specific values in an range but i did not find an way to do this.

I used it with Array but the problem is how to convert this range `C3:AG3`to use an array formula i did this which is obviously wrong `C3:C:AG3:AG` there can be other way to use countif with Array but i could not find.

Someone can please help me with that issue.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({"Count";IF(B2:B<>"",,COUNTIF(C3:AG3,"W")))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in row 1:

```
={"count"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 MMULT(IF(C2:AG="L", 1, 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:AG))^0)))}
```

[image]